# Simple C++ Program with Class and Linked List

Tags: c++, class, linked-list

Can someone help me figure this out. I have a class project where I was supposed to program a Casewell Bill in class and linked list. I cant figure it out until I found this link. It outputs very awesomely, but Idk how to add a cin>> user input, like number of adults and calculate the food total. I tried to fix it but it's not working properply
http://www.sourcetricks.com/2008/07/c-singly-linked-lists.html#.WYzSxneGOHo

//-----------------------------------------

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include <cstring>

 using namespace std;

 class List
 {
     private:
         int number;
         char* word;
         List* next;
     public:
         void inserts(int num, char* text);
         void removes(int num);
         void print();
 };
 List* first;

 void List::print() {
     cout <<"This is our list:"<<endl;

     // Temp pointer
     List *tmp = first;

     // No nodes
     if ( tmp == NULL ) {
         cout << "EMPTY list" << endl;
         return;
     }

     // One node in the list
     if ( tmp->next == NULL ) { //on the first node of the list
         cout <<"NUMBER:\t "<< tmp->number;
         cout <<"\tWORD:\t"<< tmp->word << endl;
         cout <<"--------------------------------"<<endl;

     }
     else {
     // Parse and print the list
         while ( tmp != NULL ){ //the rest of the list
              cout <<"NUMBER:\t"<< tmp->number;
              cout <<"\tWORD:\t"<< tmp->word << endl;
              cout <<"--------------------------------"<<endl;

             tmp = tmp->next;
         }
     }
 }

 void List::inserts(int num, char* word){
     // Create a new list
     List* newlist = new List; 
     newlist->number=num;

     newlist->word=word;


     newlist->next=NULL;

     // Create a temp pointer
     List *tmp = first;

     if ( tmp != NULL ) {
         // Nodes already present in the list
         // Parse to end of list
         while ( tmp->next != NULL ) {
             tmp = tmp->next;
         }

     // Point the last node to the new node
         tmp->next=newlist;
     }
     else {
         // First node in the list
         first = newlist;
     }
 }

 void List::removes(int num){
     int k = 0;
     List* tmp=first;

     if(tmp==NULL) {
         return;
        //Last node of the list
     }

    if ( tmp->next == NULL && tmp->number==num ) {
         delete tmp;
         first = NULL;
     }
     else {
         //Parse thru the nodes
         List* prev;
         prev = new List;
         while ( tmp != NULL ) {
             if ( tmp->number == num && k == 0) {
                 first = first->next;
             }
             if ( tmp->number == num){
                 break;
                 prev = tmp;
                 tmp = tmp->next;
                 k++;
             }
         }//end of while 

         //Adjust the pointers
         prev->next=(tmp->next);
         //Delete the current node
         delete tmp;
         delete prev;
     }//end of else
 }//end of void remove


 int main ()
 {

     first->print();
     first->inserts(1200,"endian");
     first->print();
     first->inserts(10,"endianness");
     first->inserts(1200,"PEEK");
     first->inserts(1200,"POKE");
     first->inserts(1200,".MIL");
     first->print();
     first->removes(100);
     first->print();
     getchar();
 }
```

And outputs with warnings

```
 5 warnings generated.
 This is our list:
 EMPTY list
 This is our list:
 NUMBER:     1200   WORD:   endian
 --------------------------------
 This is our list:
 NUMBER:    1200    WORD:   endian
 --------------------------------
 NUMBER:    10  WORD:   endianness
 --------------------------------
 NUMBER:    1200    WORD:   PEEK
 --------------------------------
 NUMBER:    1200    WORD:   POKE
 --------------------------------
 NUMBER:    1200    WORD:   .MIL
 --------------------------------
```

Comment: That's a lot of poorly indented code.  You're taking input in one place, why can't you add more?

Comment: The way you are trying to use `Node.number` suggests you should reread the first few chapters of your textbook. C++ is not a forgiving language for the unprepared.

Comment: int number cout<<"Append a number \n";
      cin>>number;
      double product = number * 2;

      list.Append(number);
      list.Print();

      list.Append(product);
      list.Print();

Comment: it's very poor question, because you didn't provide information what is _expected_ output.. and that code requires indentation.  Do not bother use space if you work in an IDE, you can ident with tab key.

Comment: sorry! for poor copy pasting and indenting. And I used Node.number to point out what I was trying to do

Comment: I would just like be able to have a class that has the following variables: numberOfAdults, costPerAdult, and adultTotalCost.

Comment: I would just like be able to have a class that has the following variables: numberOfAdults, costPerAdult, and adultTotalCost.

1))) A cout<<"How many adults? ";

cin>>numberOfAdults

2))) A constructor that will initialize the value of costPerAdult
As soon as the numberOfAdults is inputted, I want it to calculate the adultTotalCost and then output it.

3)))When the bill is finish, itll output the final bill, destructor that will delete the bill, then prompt a cout question that will grab either y/n if user would still like to create another bill. If yes that start a new Bill

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are just trying to use `cin` , for that you will have to declare definite type of input you want .for example as you said you need number it can be int
Use of `cin`

```
List list;
int number;
cout<<"Append a number \n";
cin>>number;
double product = number * 2;
```

Correctly indented code with input (using cin)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Node class
class Node {
    int data;
    Node* next;

public:
    Node() {};
    void SetData(int aData) { data = aData; };
    void SetNext(Node* aNext) { next = aNext; };
    int Data() { return data; };
    Node* Next() { return next; };
};

// List class
class List {
    Node *head;
public:
    List() { head = NULL; };
    void Print();
    void Append(int data);
    void Delete(int data);
};

/**
 * Print the contents of the list
 */
void List::Print() {

    // Temp pointer
    Node *tmp = head;

    // No nodes
    if ( tmp == NULL ) {
        cout << "EMPTY" << endl;
        return;
    }

    // One node in the list
    if ( tmp->Next() == NULL ) {
        cout << tmp->Data();
        cout << " --> ";
        cout << "NULL" << endl;
    }
    else {
        // Parse and print the list
        do {
            cout << tmp->Data();
            cout << " --> ";
            tmp = tmp->Next();
        }
        while ( tmp != NULL );

        cout << "NULL" << endl;
    }
}

/**
 * Append a node to the linked list
 */
void List::Append(int data) {

    // Create a new node
    Node* newNode = new Node();
    newNode->SetData(data);
    newNode->SetNext(NULL);

    // Create a temp pointer
    Node *tmp = head;

    if ( tmp != NULL ) {
        // Nodes already present in the list
        // Parse to end of list
        while ( tmp->Next() != NULL ) {
            tmp = tmp->Next();
        }

        // Point the last node to the new node
        tmp->SetNext(newNode);
    }
    else {
        // First node in the list
        head = newNode;
    }
}

/**
 * Delete a node from the list
 */
void List::Delete(int data) {

    // Create a temp pointer
    Node *tmp = head;

    // No nodes
    if ( tmp == NULL )
        return;

    // Last node of the list
    if ( tmp->Next() == NULL ) {
        delete tmp;
        head = NULL;
    }
    else {
        // Parse thru the nodes
        Node *prev = nullptr;
        do {
            if ( tmp->Data() == data ) break;
            prev = tmp;
            tmp = tmp->Next();
        } while ( tmp != NULL );

        // Adjust the pointers
        prev->SetNext(tmp->Next());

        // Delete the current node
        delete tmp;
    }
}

int main()
{
    // New list
    List list;
    int number;
    cout<<"Append a number \n";
    cin>>number;
    double product = number * 2;

    list.Append(number);
    list.Print();

    list.Append(product);
    list.Print();
    // Append nodes to the list
    list.Append(100);
    list.Print();
    list.Append(200);
    list.Print();
    list.Append(300);
    list.Print();
    list.Append(400);
    list.Print();
    list.Append(500);
    list.Print();

    // Delete nodes from the list
    list.Delete(400);
    list.Print();
    list.Delete(300);
    list.Print();
    list.Delete(200);
    list.Print();
    list.Delete(500);
    list.Print();
    list.Delete(100);
    list.Print();
}
```

Output

```
Append a number 
2
2 --> NULL
2 --> 4 --> NULL
2 --> 4 --> 100 --> NULL
2 --> 4 --> 100 --> 200 --> NULL
2 --> 4 --> 100 --> 200 --> 300 --> NULL
2 --> 4 --> 100 --> 200 --> 300 --> 400 --> NULL
2 --> 4 --> 100 --> 200 --> 300 --> 400 --> 500 --> NULL
2 --> 4 --> 100 --> 200 --> 300 --> 500 --> NULL
2 --> 4 --> 100 --> 200 --> 500 --> NULL
2 --> 4 --> 100 --> 500 --> NULL
2 --> 4 --> 100 --> NULL
2 --> 4 --> NULL
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: How do I delete the 2 and 4?

Comment: I would just like be able to have a class that has the following variables: numberOfAdults, costPerAdult, and adultTotalCost. 1))) A cout<<"How many adults? "; cin>>numberOfAdults 2))) A constructor that will initialize the value of costPerAdult As soon as the numberOfAdults is inputted, I want it to calculate the adultTotalCost and then output it. 3)))When the bill is finish, itll output the final bill, destructor that will delete the bill, then prompt a cout question that will grab either y/n if user would still like to create another bill. If yes that start a new Bill

Comment: @SamuelFolledo just use the delete function you created

Comment: @SamuelFolled thats easy to do ..if you want to do it in linked list you can do that ..try your code and if struck then we will help but cannot write whole code for you .Won't help you if you are trying to learn